# Function to save form $_POST information to random_name.txt

Tags: php, file

I want to save as a backup the information from an form (`$_POST`) to to a dynamic generated file.  So I have to generate one file for each user that submits an form (10 submitted forms = 10 different files).
I tried to make a function to generate a random file name and write the `$_POST` array in that file

```
function save_post($data){
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
    var_dump($randomString);
    $file = "dump/".$randomString.".txt";
    foreach ($data as $k => $v){
        $toFile = "Key: $k; Value: $v \n";
    }
    return file_put_contents($file, $toFile);
}
```

And use this function:

```
save_post($_POST);
```

Problem is that no file is generated.

Comment: remove `return $randomString;` line in between of your code!! after `return` everything is vanished

Comment: @Saty strange thing is that in the random_name.txt file I have only the last key->value but in the form I have 2 radio groups

Comment: @NeculaiAndrei I have given the ans for this

Comment: Just use `file_put_contents($file, $toFile. PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);` inside `foreach loop`
`

Comment: @Saty, Instead of writing in loop, It would be better to concatenate string and writing file once.

Comment: Yaa it can be done by `concatenate` string with too!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly like @Saty says in the comments. The issue you're having is caused because of the `return $randomString;` that you have in your code.

The [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) describe returning a value from a function as follows:

> Any type may be returned, including arrays and objects. This causes the function to end its execution immediately and pass control back to the line from which it was called.

Once you call return, no code beneath the return in that function will be executed. The code should look like this:

```
function save_post($data){
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }

    var_dump($randomString);
    $file = "dump/".$randomString.".txt";
    foreach ($data as $k => $v){
        $toFile = "Key: $k; Value: $v \n";
    }
    return file_put_contents($file, $toFile);
}
```

**It's worth noting** that as it stands, your current file only includes the last key-value pair in your loop. If my post array looked like this:

```
array("greeting" => "hello world", "farewell" => "goodbye world")
```

And I ran the script it would output a file like this (file: dump/rHsmM.txt):

```
Key: farewell; Value: goodbye world
```

If that's not what you're looking for you need to instead use [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) which will allow you to add multiple values. Instead of overriding the value of `$toFile` everytime you loop you just add to the end of it instead. To do this change your `$toFile = "Key: $k; Value: $v \n";` line to:

```
$toFile .= "Key: $k; Value: $v \n";
```

If you re-ran your script with the same array you would end up with this (dump/PFOzo.txt):

```
Key: greeting; Value: hello world
Key: farewell; Value: goodbye world
```

---

**Update**: As pointed out in the comments, you do get a notice from this about `$toFile` not existing before we attempt to concatenate it. To resolve this we can just make sure we declare it before the foreach loop like this:

```
$toFile = "";
foreach ($data as $k => $v){
...
```

Now when we come to concatenate, we already have a string to concatenate to (albeit blank).

Comment: The function is working, the file is generated and all the info is there, but I get an `Notice: Undefined variable: toFile in`

Comment: Ah, that's because we haven't actually defined the string that we are trying to concatenate. We are saying "Add this onto the end of our existing string" and PHP says "There is no existing string!". 

You can resolve that by adding `$toFile = "";` just before the foreach loop. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove or comment

   ```
   //return $randomString;
   //var_dump($randomString);
   ```
2. concatinate `$toFile`

   ```
   function save_post($data){
       $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
       $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
       $randomString = '';
       for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
           $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
       }
       //return $randomString;
       //var_dump($randomString);
       $file = "dump/".$randomString.".txt";
       $toFile = "";
       foreach ($data as $k => $v){
           $toFile .= "Key: $k; Value: $v \n";
       }
       return file_put_contents($file, $toFile);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use as below:

```
function save_post($data){
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }

    var_dump($randomString);
    $file = "dump/".$randomString.".txt";
    foreach ($data as $k => $v){
        $toFile = "Key: $k; Value: $v \n";
    }
    return file_put_contents($file, $toFile);
}
```

Note: function was returning value before performing action so cleared return statement.